# pass array to the same controller function that accepts request object in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a `testController` in which I have two function `importCustomer()` and `addUpdateCustomer(Request $request)`.

I want to pass on the `importCustomer` values to the `addUpdateCustomer` function, but the problem is I can't pass the array, because of the request object.

```php
    function importCustomer(Request $request){
       //Will read the csv file and for each record call the 
       //addUpdateCustomer function
       $dataPayload = [];
       $this->addUpdateCustomer($dataPayload);


    }
    function addUpdateCustomer(Request $request){
       //Insert if user is new else update the details if already exists.
    }
```

Comment: You can move the code to another function, which doesn't need the `$request` parameter. You can make a parameter optional. You can also create a `Request` object with the needed values. I can't say if any of those will work for you - please post some code to clarify the situation.

Comment: @PeterKrebs I have added the code snippet. Same functionality of adding customer can be achieved using the existing function addUpdateCustomer. So just to avoid code redundancy i want to use the existing function addUpdateCustomer.

Comment: Why do you need the `Request` parameter at all if you are reading from a CSV file? You can just remove the parameter. Or see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the `addUpdateCustomer` function publically accessible, meaning is there a `route` defined for it? If not just remove the `Request` object as a parameter and replace it with an `array`.

```
public function addUpdateCustomer(array $payload = [])
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Alternatively you [`merge`](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_merge) some content into the `$request`:

```
$this->addUpdateCustomer($request->merge($dataPayload));
```

Comment: addUpdateCustomer is a public API so can't alter its original function parameter

Comment: Yes route is defined for it.

Comment: @GAURAVHIRAN So use the second option and merge your array into a request object.